# Remove spaces between table cells

Tags: html, css

I have following markup

```
      <div class="dc2-search-form">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="search-form-label">
                                    <span id="StreetAddress_Label">Address</span>
                                </div><br>
                                <input style="height: 10px; width:80px" tabindex="0"
                                type="text" value="">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="search-form-label">
                                    <span id="Sales_Cycle_Label">Sales
                                    Cycle</span>
                                </div><br>
                                <input style="height: 10px; width: 80px;" tabindex="0" type="text" value="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And following CSS

```
.dc2-search-form {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 }
.dc2-search-form  table {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:0}
.dc2-search-form .search-form-label{font-size:13px;background-color:#BFBFBF;padding:10px 0 10px 1px; border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;}
.dc2-search-form table select,input{height:10px;font-size:10px;padding:2px;}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMDVw/) for reference

It gives me the desired output except for a tiny bit space between table cells. I need to make the **span div** appear as seamless one row with border on top and bottom but I am to able to accomplish that due the space.

How to remove the space between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply no padding to your table cells:

```
.dc2-search-form  table td{padding:0}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/wMDVw/2/)

Comment: CSS is *usually* the way to go (: - Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

add `cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0` to your `table`

[**update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wMDVw/1/)

`<table width="100%"  cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cellpadding and cellspacing to 0, like this:

```
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    ...stuff...
</table>
```